# Change the case of a Range text and type it

Tags: vba, object, split, range, ms-word

Possible scenario, let say we created a `Range Object` containing the following line:

Speculative BUY, FV: EGP19.59

Now I want to split the `Range Object` into two parts by ", " as `delimiter` so that the given `Range` will change into two Ranges containing "Speculative BUY" and ", FV: EGP19.59" (Two separate range).

Now I need to change the case of only the first range containing "Speculative BUY" into "Speculative Buy" using:

`.Case = wdTitleWord`

Previously I am using `.Find` to change the Ranges in the following code (this is not complete code as it is only changing the Range R, not splitting it into two):

```
Sub Range_into_Ranges()

selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, COUNT:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Dim R, F As Word.Range
Set R = selection.Range
Set F = R.Duplicate
    With F.Find
    .Text = ", "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    End With
    If F.Find.Found Then
    R.SetRange Start:=R.Start, _
    End:=F.Start
    R.Case = wdTitleWord
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** There may be other ways of producing the same results. you are free to advice me another simple code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a case to a Range using the WdCharacterCase enumeration. For title case:

```
R.Case = wdTitleWord
```

Put into the context of your sample code, something like as follows. I did some tweaking:

- My version assumes you want to work with the paragraph where the selection currently is, which is why I commented out your first two lines
- In VBA you need to declare the data type of *every* variable, otherwise it's a Variant. So: `Dim R As Word.Range`
- VBA provides the `Split` function to divide up a string according to a delimiter. I use this to get the term to search, so that you can get the Range directly
- I found when setting Title Case on text that has ALL CAPS that it doesn't reduce upper case to lower case. But first applying lower case, then title case, does work.

Sample code

```
Sub Range_into_Ranges()

'    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
'    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Dim R As word.Range, F As word.Range
    Dim sTerm As String, bFound As Boolean

    Set R = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
    R.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 'Trim off the paragraph mark
    sTerm = R.Text
    sTerm = Split(sTerm, ",")(0)
    Set F = R.Duplicate
    With F.Find
        .Text = sTerm
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        bFound = .Execute
    End With
    If bFound Then
        F.Case = wdLowerCase
        F.Case = wdTitleWord
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: when setting Title Case on text that has ALL CAPS that it doesn't reduce upper case to lower case. But first applying lower case, then title case, does work. I think this is where problem lies, and that was only the main reason my older version of code was not working. anyway thanks.

Comment: @IbneAshiq You're welcome. It does help when asking a question to provide the steps necessary to reproduce. Without the sample text I wouldn't have found that!